# unable to save setting python in Ubuntu use editor sublime text 2?

Tags: python

i installed python 2.7.9 with framework Django 1.7. i try to change databases in settings.py but cannot save (unable to save mysite/mysite/settings.py)

how solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: Make sure you have write access to `mysite/mysite/` (chmod/chown).

Comment: how to write access with chood/chown?

Comment: `chmod +w mysite/mysite/settings.py`

Comment: i already try this chmod +w /home/apsijogja/mysite/mysite/settings.py but when i still can't save. how?

Comment: Add write permissions to the folder as well. If it still doesn't work, check who's the owner of the file (`ls -l`) if it's not the user you're using - modify the ownership of the file using `chown <user> /home/apsijogja/mysite/mysite/settings.py`

Comment: i try this chmod <root> /home/apsijogja/mysite/mysite/settings.py but bash: root: No such file or directory
how?

Comment: You should go and learn some linux before digging any further. There are plenty of online tutorials to help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be permissions problems. Did you check if your user is able to write that file? If not change the permissions of the file with the file explorer or in the command line (chmod)

Comment: i already check owner is root. how to open folder project sublime with terminal?

Comment: @PointshopProject well you just need to write 'chown yourusername path/to/that/file.py' and to be sure write 'chmod +w path/to/file.py'. Obviously writing the correct username and path in both lines

Comment: i already try this. but when edit settings.py i stll can't save. or i must to open folder project sublime with terminal?

Comment: mmm weird... the try to do the above commands but with the path of the project folder and with the option -R (recursively)

Comment: i try chmod -R /home/apsijogja/mysite but chmod: missing operand after `/home/apsijogja/mysite'
how?

Comment: You still have to put the +w also (-R +w) @PointshopProject

Comment: oh God its still same. can't save i try like this chmod -R +w /home/apsijogja/mysite

Comment: Then put 777 instead of +w (chmod -R 777 path)